# javascript insert object to array at specific point id and increment others id

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have little problem with js arrays. I want to insert object  on if statement and increase id on anothers objects

```js
    var arr=[{asc_id:1, date:2018-06-29, name:"first"},
         {asc_id:2, date:2018-06-30, name:"second"}, 
         {asc_id:3, date:2018-07-10, name:"fourth"},
         {asc_id:4, date:2018-07-10, name:"fifth"}];
var checkedItem={asc_id:4, date:2018-06-30, name:"third"};

let savingDate = moment(checkedItem.date)
var newArr = arr.map((item,key)=>{
  if(savingDate.isSame(item.date) || savingDate.isAfter(item.date)){
    console.log(true)
    return{
      //code here
    }
  }else{
    return{
      //code here
    }
    console.log(false)
  }
})
console.log(newArr)
```

i want make new array looks like

```
newArr=[{asc_id:1, date:2018-06-29, name:"first"},
     {asc_id:2, date:2018-06-30, name:"second"}, 
     {asc_id:3, date:2018-06-30, name:"third"},
     {asc_id:4, date:2018-07-10, name:"fourth"},
     {asc_id:5, date:2018-07-10, name:"fifth"}];
```

map is not good idea? condition i check with momento and check statement is correct only i want how to  push object between second and fourth and make asc_id  as in code?

Comment: You're returning the same object in both `if` and `else`.

Comment: Is `date` supposed to be a string? It needs quotes around it.

Comment: ok i update with real statement

Comment: You can't use `.map()` to add to an array, it always returns an array that's the same length as the original. You can use `.splice()` to insert into an array.

Comment: Bermar any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is make a deep copy of the original array. Then insert the new element in that array at the appropriate place, and then reset all the `asc_id` properties.

```js
 var arr=[{asc_id:1, date:"2018-06-29", name:"first"},
         {asc_id:2, date:"2018-06-30", name:"second"}, 
         {asc_id:3, date:"2018-07-10", name:"fourth"},
         {asc_id:4, date:"2018-07-10", name:"fifth"}];
var checkedItem={asc_id:4, date:"2018-06-30", name:"third"};

var newArr = arr.map(e => Object.assign({}, e));
var insertPos = newArr.findIndex(({date}) => date > checkedItem.date);
if (insertPos == -1) { // If not found, insert at end
    insertPos = newArr.length;
}
newArr.splice(insertPos, 0, checkedItem);
newArr.forEach((e, i) => e.asc_id = i + 1);
console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: Would incorrectly insert if the new item is the last item, try it with a date in 2019

Comment: @HMR Good catch, added a check for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.slice(0,idx).concat([element_to_insert].concat(arr.slice(idx+1,arr.length).map(n=>{
    n.asc_id++;
    return n;
})))
```

Comment: How does this increment the `asc_id` in the elements after the one that's inserted?

Comment: @Barmar valid, I modified it a bit

Comment: Yuo also need to fix the `asc_id` of the element that you insert, so it's in the proper sequence for the place it gets.

Answer (score 0):

`.map` is not a good idea because it returns an array with the same length as the one mapped, you can use a simple `for` loop and create an empty array to fill it with values from original array and push the `checkedElement` whenever matched , for the `asc_id` create a `ndx` and increment it:

```js
var arr=[{asc_id:1, date:'2018-06-29', name:"first"},
         {asc_id:2, date:'2018-06-30', name:"second"}, 
         {asc_id:3, date:'2018-07-10', name:"fourth"},
         {asc_id:4, date:'2018-07-10', name:"fifth"}];
         
var checkedItem={asc_id:4, date:'2018-06-30', name:"third"};

var newArr = [], ndx = 0;

arr.forEach((e,i) => {
  newArr.push({ ...e, asc_id : ++ndx })
  
  if(e.date === checkedItem.date)
    newArr.push({...checkedItem, asc_id : ++ndx })
})

console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: Item is never inserted if it's the last, try with a new item that has a date in 2019. It will also never insert if it's the first, try with date in 2017

Answer (score 0):

Other answers re index the entire array, I'm not sure that's what you want, the following uses reduce and will only re index items after the inserted item.

```js
const arr = [
  { asc_id: 5, date: "2018 - 06 - 29", name: "first" },
  { asc_id: 6, date: "2018 - 06 - 30", name: "second" },
  { asc_id: 8, date: "2018 - 07 - 10", name: "fourth" },
  { asc_id: 9, date: "2018 - 07 - 10", name: "fifth" }
];
const checkedItem = { asc_id: "ignored", date: "2018 - 06 - 30", name: "third" };

const addItem = (arr,newItem)=>{
  let itemInserted=false;
  const newArray =  arr.reduce(
    (result,item) => {
      if(newItem.date.localeCompare(item.date) === -1){
        if(!itemInserted){//item has not been inserted yet
          result.push({...newItem,asc_id:item.asc_id});
          itemInserted=true;
        }
        result.push({...item,asc_id:item.asc_id+1})
      }else{
        result.push(item)
      }
      return result;
    },
    []//initial result
  );
  if(!itemInserted){//new item was the last item
    newArray.push({...newItem,asc_id:arr.slice(-1)[0].asc_id+1});
  }  
  return newArray;
}
console.log(addItem(arr,checkedItem));
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you could start implementing a function like the one I provide as part of the following runnable snippet.

Note that the first parameter is a condition: use `moment` or whatever to parse a date or operate with any property of any of the existing items.

See how `insertWhen` is a high order function which takes two different functions `cond` and `comparer`:

- `cond` is a function that should return true or false when evaluating each given array item to find where to insert the new item.
- `compare` is a function that should return `-1` if you want to add the item before the found one, or `1` if you want to add the item after the found one. **This function may use `moment` to return `-1` or `1` depending on your needs**.

---

### Inserts the new item after the matched one

```js
const arr = [{
    asc_id: 1,
    date: '2018 - 06 - 29',
    name: "first"
  },
  {
    asc_id: 2,
    date: '2018 - 06 - 30',
    name: "second"
  },
  {
    asc_id: 3,
    date: '2018 - 07 - 10',
    name: "fourth"
  },
  {
    asc_id: 4,
    date: '2018 - 07 - 10',
    name: "fifth"
  }
]

const insertWhen = (cond, comparer, newItem, arr) => {
  const foundItem = arr.find(cond)

  if (!foundItem) return

  let foundItemIndex = arr.indexOf(foundItem)

  switch (comparer(foundItem, newItem)) {
    case -1:
      arr.splice(foundItemIndex + 1, 0, newItem)

      arr.slice(foundItemIndex + 1)
        .forEach(item => (item.asc_id = ++foundItemIndex + 1))
      break

    case 1:
      arr.splice(foundItemIndex, 0, newItem)

      arr.slice(foundItemIndex)
        .forEach(item => (item.asc_id = ++foundItemIndex))
      break

  }
}

var newItem = {
  asc_id: 4,
  date: '2018-06-30',
  name: "third"
}

insertWhen(
  ({ date }) => date == '2018 - 06 - 30',
  (foundItem, newItem) => -1, // INSERT AFTER, wins foundItem
  newItem,
  arr
)

console.log(arr)
```

---

### Inserts the new item before the matched one

```js
const arr = [{
    asc_id: 1,
    date: '2018 - 06 - 29',
    name: "first"
  },
  {
    asc_id: 2,
    date: '2018 - 06 - 30',
    name: "second"
  },
  {
    asc_id: 3,
    date: '2018 - 07 - 10',
    name: "fourth"
  },
  {
    asc_id: 4,
    date: '2018 - 07 - 10',
    name: "fifth"
  }
]

const insertWhen = (cond, comparer, newItem, arr) => {
  const foundItem = arr.find(cond)

  if (!foundItem) return

  let foundItemIndex = arr.indexOf(foundItem)

  switch (comparer(foundItem, newItem)) {
    case -1:
      arr.splice(foundItemIndex + 1, 0, newItem)

      arr.slice(foundItemIndex + 1)
        .forEach(item => (item.asc_id = ++foundItemIndex + 1))
      break

    case 1:
      arr.splice(foundItemIndex, 0, newItem)

      arr.slice(foundItemIndex)
        .forEach(item => (item.asc_id = ++foundItemIndex))
      break

  }
}

var newItem = {
  asc_id: 4,
  date: '2018-06-30',
  name: "third"
}

insertWhen(
  ({ date }) => date == '2018 - 06 - 30',
  (foundItem, newItem) => 1, // INSERT BEFORE, wins the new item
  newItem,
  arr
)

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Item will never be inserted if it's the last, try it with a new item that has a date in 2019

Comment: @HMR Maybe I'm mistaken, but it seems like the OP wants to insert an item between some given date or after one. I don't know if the OP wants to insert the item as the last one if `cond` is never `true`.

Comment: @HMR BTW, what has to do the date in 2019? For me, it seems like I should refactor the snippet so it uses a comparer instead of a condition, so the comparer may decide if it goes before or after the found item.